# GA4 Custom Insights - Daily anomaly issues

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

Has anyone found the GA4 custom insights feature useful for detecting anomalies?
Is there a way to customise the custom insights daily frequency to record later in the day, or would moving to a weekly frequency be more accurate?
I've set up insights with a daily evaluation frequency on revenue, users by channel, etc with the condition 'Has anomaly', with the intention of picking up any site tracking issues. Sounds great right?
However, I'm being sent insight alerts from the GA4 properties early in the day (really early, like 4-5 am early) saying users and revenue have dropped. When I check at 9am though, the revenue and users haven't dropped at all, the numbers are different to what the insight is reporting. I understand GA4 takes up to 24 hours to fully attribute data, so why are custom insights being triggered so early in the day before it has a chance to give an accurate measurement?